# Cockpit group privileges

Tags: centos, permissions, cockpit

I'm using **CentOS 8** and I wanted to monitor my server using Cockpit but my users cannot restart/stop/start service. Only the root user and the wheel group can manage them, and I don't want the root user to be used to log in to my server. I have a monitoring group for the server called **agents**. So I added this code to my rules:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
        if (subject.isInGroup("agents")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
});
```

But it still won't allow my monitoring team to control my services. I also tried this rule:

```
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:agents"];
});
```

Which will allow my monitoring team to do administrative actions. But I don't really want them to be able to do that though, just the normal start/stop services. Can somebody help me? Thanks.